# Play button won't start video once video is finished

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-video

I have a play/pause button for a video player im making. Once the video has gone trough one play through, I'd like the play button to have the video start again, but it doesn't.

Here's the script im using:

```
function play(){
        if(!media.paused && !media.ended){
        media.pause();
        playButton.innerHTML='Play';
        window.clearInterval(updateBar);
    }else{
        media.play();
        playButton.innerHTML='Pause';
        updateBar=setInterval(update, 100)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about structuring your function like this

```
function play(){
    if (!media.paused) { // if currently playing (or ended?)
        if (media.ended) { // if at the end
            media.currentTime = 0; // go to start 
        } else { // else
            media.pause(); // pause
            playButton.innerHTML='Play';
            window.clearInterval(updateBar);
            return; // and end function here
        }
    } // then if function didn't end
    media.play(); // resume playing
    playButton.innerHTML='Pause';
    updateBar=setInterval(update, 100);
}
```

The DOM Interface you're using is [**HTMLMediaElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLMediaElement).

Comment: If I do it like this. Because media.play is outside he if statement - wouldn't the video play when I want to pause it?

Comment: The `return;` kills the function after pausing so it won't play. I am, however, making the assumption "at the end of the video, `.ended === true && .paused === false`". If that is wrong, put the `if (media.ended)` check before the paused check, which changes to an `else if`

Comment: So yea I tried the new lines but it still won't replay the video. What it does is switch the text to pause and back to play very quickly.

Comment: I think the problem has to do with the currentTime call. I have a button called volume so i attached an onclick attribute to call a function "level" function level(){media.CurrentTime = 120;}  But when I click on volume it doesn't go to two minutes in. It doesn't do anything.